# Android Studio TextView Init C++

Tags: java, android, c++, textview

I am trying to create a new TextView via c++. My problem is init a new TextView. There is no such method that goes by init. The class itself is huge and I cannot seem to find exactly what I am looking for. To sum it up, I need a TextView method to call in c++ that replaces `new` in java.

Here is what I am working with so far. Also, yes, I understand I still need to implement more code to add the view to my screen.

`jclass textView = env->FindClass("android/widget/TextView");
    jmethodID newTextView = env->GetStaticMethodID(textView, "<init>", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/widget/TextView");
    jmethodID setText = env->GetMethodID(textView, "setText", "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(env->CallStaticObjectMethod(textView, newTextView, "Lcom/menu/Beyond;"), setText, env->NewStringUTF("TextView Spawned"));`

**UPDATE 1**
One new idea is simply to call a java method from c++ that creates a new TextView. It'll store this TextView object into a global TextView array that can be accessed from c++. I have not accessed a java field from c++ before, so if someone can beat me to it, I would appreciate the help. If anyone has a solution to init a new TextView from c++ without java, that would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `<init>` is red and appears to not be valid, once compiled and run, this method is indeed available for use. Now as far as creating this new TextView, NewObject is used to do so. Below is the code used to create this new TextView. Keep in mind, not everything regarding adding the view, grabbing activity/service context, etc is here. This below is purely just an example.

`jclass textViewClass = globalEnv->FindClass("android/widget/TextView");
    jmethodID textViewInit = globalEnv->GetMethodID(textViewClass, "<init>", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V");
    jfieldID rebornContextID = globalEnv->GetFieldID(rebornClass, "rebornContext", "Landroid/content/Context;");
    jobject rebornContext = globalEnv->GetObjectField(rebornObject, rebornContextID);
    jobject textView0 = globalEnv->NewObject(textViewClass, textViewInit, rebornContext);`